# Как создать RecyclerView c передвигаемыми элементами?

Tags: android, github, listview, material-design, android-material

Как создать RecyclerView c элементами которые можно как бы вытаскивать из списка и вставить на другую позицию? Не копирование / вставка, перетаскивание. Элементом является CardView. Есть ли какая библиотека?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему вам ну;но вот это: [android-advancedrecyclerview](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

Вот пример работы на [youTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=S7cSwMArjUQ)